# How to add a new value to a range in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Using this code I'm displaying the values from 0px to 150px in a select box:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'ot_recognized_line_heights' ) ) {

function ot_recognized_line_heights( $field_id ) {

$range = ot_range( 
  apply_filters( 'ot_line_height_low_range', 0, $field_id ), 
  apply_filters( 'ot_line_height_high_range', 150, $field_id ), 
  apply_filters( 'ot_line_height_unit_type', 1, $field_id )
);

$unit = apply_filters( 'ot_line_height_unit_type', 'px', $field_id );

foreach( $range as $k => $v ) {
  $range[$k] = $v . $unit;
}

return $range;
}

}
```

I need to add the new value "inherit" in order to display it as option in the select box, but I don't have idea about how to do that.

I already tried using `$range .= "inherit"` before the `return` but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

This is the function `ot_range`:

```
function ot_range( $start, $limit, $step = 1 ) {

if ( $step < 0 )
  $step = 1;

$range = range( $start, $limit, $step );

foreach( $range as $k => $v ) {
if ( strpos( $v, 'E' ) ) {
  $range[$k] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for the negative vote. That was so "helpful"...

Comment: Hi Gerard. I've not downvoted, but people are welcome to downvote here. I'm not sure the question is too clear - is `$range` the array from which your menu is generated?

Comment: Looks like someone gave you a negative vote because you weren't clear enough. It looks like you're using WordPress (something you probably want to indicate)

Comment: you want to add an `option` for a `select` with a value `inherit`? like this? `<option value="inherit">Inheriteringing</option>`

Comment: Right, @Deadpool. The range already works, it shows from 0px to 150px counting +1, and I want to add an extra option.

Comment: Yes, @djthoms, it's on WordPress (using the Option-Tree framework), but the question is more related to PHP. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: I answered, but I can edit if you post a `print_r($range);`

Comment: Thanks, @AbraCadaver. If I use the `print_r` instead of the `return`, it still shows the list, from 0px to 150px. The other answer didn't work, it keeps showing all the values from 0 to 150 except the "inherit" option.

Comment: Yeah, we need to see what the actual array looks like.  Try `print_r($range); die();`

Comment: Yes @halfer, it is. The menu works at the moment, it shows a list from 0px to 150px counting +1 every time. I only need to add the "inherit" option to that range, as an extra option (doesn't matter the position, the top or the bottom).

Comment: @AbraCadaver, I'm trying it to everywhere but it doesn't show the array. It seems complicated.

Comment: Gerard, sorry, I need to revert your last edit - we don't mark questions as `[solved]` in the title (the tick does that) and we don't enter into debates about downvotes _in_ posts (that belongs in the comments). You can re-post some of that in the comments from the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23392325/revisions) if you wish, but personally I wouldn't bother - the odd downvote is nothing to worry about, and is par for the course here. Glad you solved it!

Comment: Ok, @halfer. I only explained what I thought it was right. But no problem, it's ok :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what the keys in the array are, but if it is numerical then:

```
$range[] = "inherit";
return $range;
```

Comment: It might be an associative array, in which case you'd need to give it a key value (don't think it is possible to tell from the question, mind you).